# Video Format that Works on Mobile Phones

Tags: video, mobile, html5-video, file-format

I looked on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882148/playing-video-files-options-for-mobile-phones) but I am not sure if this is the answer to my question or not.

I want to be able to stream videos on a mobile web page. I want this page to be compatable with as many phones as I can. Smart phones are the most important, and I need it to work for:

- Android
- HTC (Many use Android, same compatibility?)
- iPhones
- Blackberries (newer brands, 5.0 or higher if need be, but possible as low as 4.0)
- Windows Phones

The rest can be added to my "it would be nice if it worked on.." list.

What video format should I use for all of these? The referenced SO question suggested mp4 files, but I have also read that some require OOG files (I think blackberry?) Is this correct? Is there one format that will work for at least all of the above brands?

I will be trying to use HTML5 for all supported phones (all but blackberry, and some windows phones cover this)

I have also read that the `<object>` tag is the best bet for getting videos onto Blackberry and Windows phones, if that is at all helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't come a cross one single mobile that doesn't support the MPEG-4 container format, including [blackberry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/video_support_723832_11.jsp). The sort of defacto video standard for high quality video is [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC). I would say that is a very safe combination if the target is reasonable *new* phones. If you really need to make sure to support everything there is, then MPEG-4 container format together with MPEG-4 Visual Simple Profile has been supported by "everyone" dating back to at least 2004...

Answer (score 2):

We tested a variety of Android devices and all of the recent models (Android 2.2/2.3) do support MPEG 4/H.264, the same goes for iPhone and afaik the Windows Phone (from what I read, I did not try personally). I don't know about Blackberry.