# Android media controller doesn't play sound for iOS recorded videos

Tags: android, ios, video, nginx, video-streaming

I am currently developing a video streaming feature for one of my android apps. I am using android media framework for the purpose. Videos are streamed from an **nginx server**. Android recorded videos works fine but iOS recorded videos plays **only the video not the sound**.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the android support limited codecs in-built like mp3,mp4,mpeg.

While iphone support most of codecs.

What is the way to resolve this?

MP4 for video and MP3 for audio are widely accepted and work on both platforms.

So you need do some stuff at the server. Implement the ffmpeg library that will convert all the videos to MP4 and audio to MP3.

We are doing same mechanism to resolve this issue.

> Some more information to understand the problem
>
> Refer stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12700725/4894556)

Hope This may help you to get the rid of your problem

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this method.